# Configuring SSL certificate on OS X 10.8.5 produces "Chain issues Contains anchor" error

Tags: tls, macos

I'm trying to install a Thawte SSL123 certificate on OS X 10.8.5, but having a difficulty. While the certificate and intermediates appear to be installed without any errors, running the Qualys SSL Labs report produces a "Chain issues   Contains anchor" message. Running openssl s_client -showcerts -connect externalcortex.com:443 command shows a duplicate (see below)

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 /C=ZA/ST=Western Cape/L=Cape Town/O=Thawte Consulting cc/OU=Certification Services Division/CN=Thawte Premium Server CA/emailAddress=premium-server@thawte.com
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/OU=Go to https://www.thawte.com/repository/index.html/OU=Thawte SSL123 certificate/OU=Domain Validated/CN=externalcortex.com
   i:/C=US/O=Thawte, Inc./OU=Domain Validated SSL/CN=Thawte DV SSL CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
1 s:/OU=Go to https://www.thawte.com/repository/index.html/OU=Thawte SSL123 certificate/OU=Domain Validated/CN=externalcortex.com
   i:/C=US/O=Thawte, Inc./OU=Domain Validated SSL/CN=Thawte DV SSL CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2 s:/C=US/O=Thawte, Inc./OU=Domain Validated SSL/CN=Thawte DV SSL CA
   i:/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./OU=Certification Services Division/OU=(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=thawte Primary Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
3 s:/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./OU=Certification Services Division/OU=(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=thawte Primary Root CA
   i:/C=ZA/ST=Western Cape/L=Cape Town/O=Thawte Consulting cc/OU=Certification Services Division/CN=Thawte Premium Server CA/emailAddress=premium-server@thawte.com
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
4 s:/C=ZA/ST=Western Cape/L=Cape Town/O=Thawte Consulting cc/OU=Certification Services Division/CN=Thawte Premium Server CA/emailAddress=premium-server@thawte.com
   i:/C=ZA/ST=Western Cape/L=Cape Town/O=Thawte Consulting cc/OU=Certification Services Division/CN=Thawte Premium Server CA/emailAddress=premium-server@thawte.com
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/OU=Go to https://www.thawte.com/repository/index.html/OU=Thawte SSL123 certificate/OU=Domain Validated/CN=externalcortex.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Thawte, Inc./OU=Domain Validated SSL/CN=Thawte DV SSL CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 6318 bytes and written 328 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: C88DB986D7A10D5FB17737D335153FF382E61A8564348235746A23B484E5630A
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: CDA9E6D3FC8E8E5D7CCA7D3240FCA8E4BECFF3381064AFFE130B2E9DC2E0B471CC01D3C41E22792 5CB8197349606E047
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1381459203
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Anchor" here means *trust anchor*: nominally, the named-and-public-key which is known *a priori* by the SSL client, and used to validate the server's certificate. *Traditionally*, trust anchors are encoded as certificates, which is a kind of a stretch because a number of fields in a certificate do not make much sense for a trust anchor.

In particular, a certificate has a `SubjectDN` field and an `IssuerDN` field, the latter being equal to the `SubjectDN` of the certificate issuer. A trust anchor has no issuer, so when the trust anchor is encoded as a certificate, it is *customary* to set the `IssuerDN` to the same value as the `SubjectDN` (the certificate is then "self-issued"). This is what you observe; it is not a "duplicate". Similarly, a certificate is signed, so there is a `signature` field to be filled; trust anchors are then often self-signed. A trust anchor encoded as a self-issued, self-signed certificate is also known as a "trusted root", or "root certificate", or "root CA", or a few other terminology variants.

When the SSL server talks with the SSL client, the server sends its certificate as part of a chain, beginning with a trust anchor and ending on the server's certificate proper. Then the question is: should the trust anchor, assuming that it is encoded as a certificate, be sent as part of the chain ? Sending that certificate is useless, because if the client is to validate the chain, then it must already have it. Nevertheless, it is **allowed** to send the trust anchor. [The standard says so](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2):

> Because
> certificate validation requires that root keys be distributed
> independently, the self-signed certificate that specifies the root
> certificate authority MAY be omitted from the chain, under the
> assumption that the remote end must already possess it in order to
> validate it in any case.

Your server apparently sends the trust anchor. It would be exaggerated to call it an "issue": the standard allows it. At most, we could say that you may omit this trust anchor with no ill effect, and it would save a little bandwidth (about 1 kB per full handshake; the effect will usually not be significant).

(SSL Labs is known to award bad points and pronounce anathemas on details which are, actually, purely cosmetic.)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. It appears I managed to correctly configure SSL on my server then :)